# Static TableView transparent header

Tags: ios, uitableview

I want to achieve next things in my UITableViewController:

1. Have transparent table Header View with fixed height.
2. Have solid colored Table Footer View (for example with white color).

To achieve this I need to set my TableViews’ background to clearColor. But once I set whole tableView backgroundColor to clearColor my header and footer also gets transparent, and I don’t need footerView as transparent.

You may say: use `TableView` inside `UIViewController`, but I can’t do it, because I’m using static cells with dynamic height, and static `TableView` will never conform `UITableViewDataSource` protocol (only way to change cell heights dynamically), because I haven’t got methods like tableView(cellForRowAtIndexPath).

[image: Example image]

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `tableFooterView` property:

```
tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I’ve tried, but it isn’t works. That hides separators at footerView only, but footer view is still transparent.

Comment: What about then doing `tableView.tableFooterView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()`

Comment: No, it’s now working, because UIView has no size. If I will specify size for UIView it will work, but I will receive unnecessary scroll